# Verilog output is undefined

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, decoder, testbench

I'm very new to Verilog, and I'm not quite sure I'm getting it. I have a 4x16 decoder module that utilizes two 3x8 modules I've included from a separate file that worked under simulation. The problem is even though the test bench is providing the correct inputs, the output is undefined (XXXXXXXXXXX) so I'm pretty sure the 4 to 16 decoder is not returning the output as it should. Any help with this project would be much appreciated.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module decoder4_16test;

    // Inputs
    reg [3:0] d;
    
    // Outputs
    wire [15:0] o;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    decoder4_16 uut (
        .d(d), 
        .o(o)
    );

    reg clk;
    reg [3:0] count;

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        d = 0;
        count = 0;
        clk = 0;
        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #100;
        forever #10 clk = ~clk;
    end

    always @(posedge clk) begin
    //  if (count > 3) count = 0;
        d <= count[3:0];
        count <= count + 1; 
   end
endmodule
```

4 to 16 decoder (XXXbrokenXXX)

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module decoder4_16(
    //inputs
    input [3:0] d,
    output reg [15:0] o
);

    wire en1, en2;
//  assign en1 = d[3];
    assign en1 = 1;
//  assign en2 = ~d[3];
    assign en2 = 0;
    
    decoder3_8 a(
        .d(d[2:0]),
        .en(en1), 
        .o(o[7:0])
    );
    
    decoder3_8 b(
        .d(d[2:0]), 
        .en(en2),
        .o(o[15:8])
    );
    
endmodule
```

3 to 8 decoder

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module decoder3_8(
        //Inputs
        input [2:0] d,
        input en,
        //outputs
        output reg [7:0] o
        );

    //combinational logic
        always @(*) begin
                //conditional cases
                if(en) begin
                        case(d)
                                //converts binary comb to output wire
                                3'd7: o=8'd128;
                                3'd6: o=8'd64;
                                3'd5: o=8'd32;
                                3'd4: o=8'd16;
                                3'd3: o=8'd8;
                                3'd2: o=8'd4;
                                3'd1: o=8'd2;
                                3'd0: o=8'd1;
                                default: o = 8'd0;
                        endcase
                        if (!en) o = 8'd0;
                end
                //default case
                else
                        o=8'd0;
        end         
endmodule
```

[image]

*edit* changing the output type from reg to wire fixed the problem. The test bench now looks normal.

[image]

Comment: Did you get any warnings or errors when you compiled `decoder4_16`? The output should NOT be declared as a `reg`, since it's being connected directly to submodule outputs. Also, I don't think it matters in this case, but I would use `<=` assignments in `decoder3_8`.

Answer (score 2):

In `decoder4_16` you declare `o` to be a reg type, but then you connect it to an output of a module instance. For a net that will be driven by a module instance output, you need to declare it as a wire type (for an output of the module being written, just remove the `reg` qualifier).

Other than that I don't see any glaring errors.

Make sure you test `decoder3_8` and make sure it is working correctly before starting on `decoder4_16`.

Comment: 3_8 was working before I started. Changing reg to wire on my output did the trick. Thank you very much.